# login - different user roles

Tags: php, mysqli

I have users table with a role field that stores Admin and Customer.I want the user with admin role to redirect to admin and the other redirect to index.php.

I'm not sure how to do this because I have encrypted the password from the registration form and using the password_verify function to give the user access if both passwords matches.

```
 function login_user() {


if(isset($_POST['btnlogin'])) {

    global $connection;

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $login_query = "SELECT * from users where email = '{$email}'";

    $confirm = mysqli_query($connection, $login_query);




    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($confirm)) {

        $db_pass = $row['password'];
        $first_name = $row['first_name'];
        $last_name = $row['last_name'];
        $contact_num = $row['mobile'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $postcode = $row['postcode'];
        $role = $row['role'];

        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $first_name;
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $last_name;
        $_SESSION['mob'] = $contact_num;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['postcode'] = $postcode;


    }


    if(password_verify($password, $db_pass)) {

                  redirect("index.php");

             }
         }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple if-condition:

```
if (password_verify($password, $db_pass)) {
    if ($role == 'admin') {    // or how do you store role value
        redirect("admin.php");
    } else {
        redirect("index.php");
    }         
}
```

Going further you should add `role` to your `$_SESSION` too.
Something like:

```
// code goes here
$_SESSION['postcode'] = $postcode;
$_SESSION['is_admin'] = $role == 'admin';
```

You need to do this so as to check if someone who directly accesses `admin.php` is **admin** or not.

Comment: I have did this before on this site. In the database I have a user called steven with role = admin. This statement skips the first condition and goes to the next condition which is index.php

Comment: This __should__ work. Check your values in database again. Check value of `role` field especially. Post additional code to your question if needed.

Comment: I checked my database and the role equals to Admin for user Steven. Instead of going to admin it keeps going to index.php... So weird.

Comment: Do you compare role with `admin` or with `Admin`? What is the `var_dump` of `role` value? Maybe there're extra spaces?

Comment: I compare role with the value "Admin".

Comment: Thanks so much though